# how to specify temperature and max_new_tokens in the curl request to Llama 2 in Huggingface Inference Endpoint?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface, llama

I'm new to AI, so apologies if wrong terminology used here.

I'm extracting some information from a body of text, and have setup Llama 2 in Huggingface via their Inference Endpoint so I can call it via curl.

The curl works for short inputs and generated_text answers, but for longer responses the answers seem to be severely truncated, like only a few words whereas I'm expecting to receive a lot more.

So I wanted to set max_new_tokens to a large number and temperature to 0, but I didn't see how to do that.  I don't care if it's set in the curl call or configured directly in the model, either is fine.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this format to input the parameters via the Inference API when using cURL:

```
def query():
    json_body = {
        "inputs": 'sample input',
        "parameters": {"max_new_tokens":4096, "top_p":0.9,"temperature":0.7}
    }
response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=json_body)
query()
```

Comment: Try to format the code block with proper syntax highlighting follow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks